# Unable to get base64 data from ImagePicker in Expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I am currently trying to develop a simple application using Expo and react-native and have run into a problem that i cannot overcome.
I need to aquire pictures in the base64 format both using camera and from gallery. For this purpose I decided to use the ImagePicker expo component.
When I access pictures form gallery using

```
const responsey = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({base64: true, quality: 1,});
```

It works like a charm, but when I try to access camera feed via

```
const response = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({base64: true, quality: 1,});
```

The promise never resolves and the application is stuck waiting for it.
I read in documentation about the ImagePicker.getPendingResultAsync() method and tried using is as such:

```
  const prom1 =  ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({base64: true, quality: 1,});
  const prom2 = ImagePicker.getPendingResultAsync();
  response = await any([prom1,prom2]);
```

But the result of this is an empty array (I imagin returned instantly form the second promise)
Where any is the function from promise.any package.

Additionaly I have noticed that when I don't request the base64 format the promise from launchCameraAsync resolves just fine.
I am reunning the appliaction on Android 10.

I am struggling to resolve this problem and been stuck on int for several days, I would be gratefull for any advice or direction as to how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Arrange your code like that to get the base 64 value.

```
const openCamera = async () => {
    // Ask the user for the permission to access the camera
    const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert("You've refused to allow this appp to access your camera!");
      return;
    }

    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      base64: true,
      quality: 1,
    });

    // Explore the result
    console.log(result.base64);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the image's file uri which looks like this - `file://.....`

Get this `uri` and change the file to `base64` format using [ImageManipulator](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/) from Expo.

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately it frezzes on the promise returned by ImageManipulator when I try to get the base64 format.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to add base64: true

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
allowsEditing: true,
aspect: [4, 3],
quality: 1,
base64: true,
```

});